# Retrofit Request and response interceptor

Tags: android, retrofit2

How to use request and response interceptor at the same time as i have use the following code snippet for request and response interceptor.

For Request Intercept :

```
@Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    RequestBody oldBody = request.body();
    if(request.method().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
        Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
        oldBody.writeTo(buffer);
        String strOldBody = buffer.readUtf8();
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"original req "+strOldBody);
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        String strNewBody = "data="+Encryption.encryptString(URLDecoder.decode(strOldBody).replace("data=",""));//EncryptionInterceptor.encryptString(strOldBody);

        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"strNewBody "+strNewBody);
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, strNewBody);
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"content type is "+body.contentType().toString());
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"content length is "+String.valueOf(body.contentLength()));
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"method is "+request.method());
        request = request.newBuilder().header("Content-Type", body.contentType().toString())
                .header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(body.contentLength()))
                .method(request.method(), body).build();
    }
    return chain.proceed(request);
}
```

For Response Interceptor:

```
 @Override public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException { Request request = chain.request();

    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
    try {
        final String responseString = new String(response.body().bytes() );
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Response: " + responseString);
        String  newResponseString = Encryption.decryptString(responseString);
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Response edited: " + newResponseString);
        return  response.newBuilder()
                .body(ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), newResponseString))
                .build();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Combine both the functions return response from the last function. You can directly read response from `chain.proceed(request);`

Comment: what about request?as i also want to intercept the request

Comment: Updated as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();
    RequestBody oldBody = request.body();

    if(request.method().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")){
        Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
        oldBody.writeTo(buffer);

        String strOldBody = buffer.readUtf8();
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"original req "+strOldBody);
        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        String strNewBody = "data="+Encryption.encryptString(URLDecoder.decode(strOldBody).replace("data=",""));//EncryptionInterceptor.encryptString(strOldBody);

        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"strNewBody "+strNewBody);
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, strNewBody);

        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"content type is "+body.contentType().toString());
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"content length is "+String.valueOf(body.contentLength()));
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"method is "+request.method());

        request = request.newBuilder().header("Content-Type", body.contentType().toString())
        .header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(body.contentLength()))
        .method(request.method(), body).build();
    }


    Response response = chain.proceed(request);
    try {
        final String responseString = new String(response.body().bytes() );

        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Response: " + responseString);

        String  newResponseString = Encryption.decryptString(responseString);

        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "Response edited: " + newResponseString);
        return  response.newBuilder()
                .body(ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), newResponseString))
        .build();

      }catch (Exception ex){
            return response;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brother.. :)